# How to put two chartjs's charts, so they both would appear?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, chartjs-2.6.0

I making a page for teachers where they can see a score their students' score and for that there are charts to show the amount of students got correct on each question. I tried to just put two charts, but it only shows one of the charts and the other chart has been as a blank. I thought the problem if happening because both charts has the same name, but after I changed one of the names of the chart, but it still only shows one of the charts. Here this is my php/html/js code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['question'])) {

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");

    if ($con->connect_error) {

        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `chapter 7 vocabulary test` WHERE `score".$_GET["question"]."`='1'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $full = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `chapter 7 vocabulary test` WHERE `score".$_GET["question"]."`='0'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $none = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    mysqli_free_result($result);

?>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="Chart.js"></script>

<div id="canvas"><canvas id="questioncan1" style="height: 25vh; width: 25vh;"></canvas></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    let myChart = document.getElementById('questioncan1').getContext("2d");

    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Arial";

    Chart.defaults.defaultFontSize = 18;

    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "black";

    let questioncan1 = new Chart(myChart, {

        type: "doughnut",

        data: {

            labels: [

                "Full Credit",
                "No Credit"

            ],

            datasets: [

                {

                    data: [

                        5,
                        15

                    ],

                    backgroundColor: [

                        "#11FF00",
                        "#F7301E"


                    ],

                    borderWidth: 0

                }

            ]

        },

        options: {

            scaleShowLabels: false,
            responsive: false,
            legend: {

                display: false

            }

        }

    });

</script>

<br><br>

<table>

    <tr>

        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>

    </tr>

    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `chapter 7 vocabulary test`";

        $result = $con->query($sql);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE  `snumber`='".$row["snumber"]."'";

            $result2 = $con->query($sql2);

            while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

                echo "<tr><td>".$row2['name']."</td><td>".$row["score".$_GET['question']]."</td></tr>";

            }

        }

    ?>

</table>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas"><canvas id="questioncan" style="height: 25vh; width: 25vh;"></canvas></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    let myChart = document.getElementById('questioncan').getContext("2d");

    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Arial";

    Chart.defaults.defaultFontSize = 18;

    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "black";

    let questioncan = new Chart(myChart, {

        type: "doughnut",

        data: {

            labels: [

                "Full Credit",
                "No Credit"

            ],

            datasets: [

                {

                    data: [

                        <?php echo $full; ?>,
                        <?php echo $none; ?>

                    ],

                    backgroundColor: [

                        "#11FF00",
                        "#F7301E"


                    ],

                    borderWidth: 0

                }

            ]

        },

        options: {

            scaleShowLabels: false,
            responsive: false,
            legend: {

                display: false

            }

        }

    });

</script>

<br><br>

<table>

    <tr>

        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>

    </tr>

    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `chapter 7 vocabulary test`";

        $result = $con->query($sql);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE  `snumber`='".$row["snumber"]."'";

            $result2 = $con->query($sql2);

            while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

                echo "<tr><td>".$row2['name']."</td><td>".$row["score".$_GET['question']]."</td></tr>";

            }

        }

    ?>

</table>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Your code is not structured. Please try to use json data with ajax will let you reach the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the variable "myChart" twice globally, rather than in separate functions, so it's only outputting one of them.

Set the second chart to:

```
  let myChart2 = document.getElementById('questioncan2').getContext("2d");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xea4qr8k/12/

Also recommend changing your div IDs to be unique, and remove the second script src for jQuery.